# Script en python para descargar serie histórica de precios a través de API de EOD

Tags: python, api, pandas

Quiero realizar un pequeño script en python que obtenga los datos históricos de una serie de activos y los almacene en un dataframe, utilizando Python pandas. Para ello el data vendor EOD https://eodhistoricaldata.com/financial-apis/python-example/ dispone de una API que permite descargarlos de forma sencilla, peor yo no consigo hacerlo. Quiero descargar el histórico de cada uno de los activos a un dataframe.

Existe un código de ejemplo pero no soy capaz de entenderlo y que funcione. El código de ejemplo es:

````
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
def get_eod_data(symbol=”AAPL.US”, api_token=”xxxx”, session=None):
if session is None:
session = requests.Session()
url = ‘https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/%s’ % symbol
params = {“api_token”: api_token}
r = session.get(url, params=params)
if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text), skipfooter=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, engine=’python’)
return df
else:raise Exception(r.status_code, r.reason, url)```
````

Comment: ¿El código de la pregunta es correcto? Si tienes el código como el de tu pregunta, es normal que no funcione, hay graves errores de sintaxis y de identación.

Comment: Sí, eso me parecía. Sin embargo es el que ponen como ejemplo a realizar. El resto ya viene en Github [enlace](https://github.com/femtotrader/python-eodhistoricaldata)

Comment: Te recomendaría que siguieras los ejemplos de github ya que están hechos en formato código. También puedes hacer tutoriales básicos de Python o algún curso que te ayude a identificar dichos errores, son errores muy básicos en Python, y si no los conoces es imposible programar.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene varios errores de sintaxis, te quedo como estaría bien escrito y la explicación:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#Iniciamos un nuevo bloque con la definición de una función. IDENTAMOS
def get_eod_data(symbol="AAPL.US", api_token="xxxx", session=None):
    #Iniciamos un nuevo bloque con el if. IDENTAMOS
    if session is None:
        session = requests.Session()
    #Se acaba el bloque, quitamos la identación
    
    url = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/%s" % symbol
    params = {"api_token": api_token}
    r = session.get(url, params=params)

    #Creamos un nuevo bloque con otro condicional, IDENTAMOS
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text), skipfooter=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, engine="python")
        return df
    #Creamos otro bloque por si no se da la primera condición, IDENTAMOS
    else:
        raise Exception(r.status_code, r.reason, url)

#Se acaba la función
```

**Identación:** En Python la identación (el tabulador) es importante, indica que se va a iniciar un nuevo bloque de código, **no es un tema visual, como sucede en otros lenguajes de programación**. Se utiliza para crear funciones, condicionales, bucles, etc. Si no entiendes esto, básicamente es imposible programar en Python.